# How to deny access to a specific "upload" folder under App_Data for specific users in asp.net mvc2?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a folder which users can upload their docs inside that.its call upload folder.it is located underneath app_data in solution explorer.I want the users to see just their own uploaded docs not others and restrict any direct access to other articles.
I also have an admin user which i want to be able to access all the docs uploaded and be able to download the file.
how could i :
1.restrict users
2.write code to download uploaded file
thanks in advance.

Comment: This question covers a lot of ground, too much for one question, and there's really no one specific answer for this. As a broad outline you want to maintain a table somewhere that tracks document ownership.  Use controller logic to control access to the documents based on this table.  Have controller/actions that filter access; don't let users directly access the folder - they must go through an action that enforces your security. If you have some specific questions about code that you've implemented to do that sort of thing, come back and ask them.

Answer (score 0):

Well, what is the problem? Close this folder to access it using direct links (if you are using App_Data it's already done) and create httphandler that returns file data. In httphandler change look have the user have access to request file